# Sharing photo's to Instagram for iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

I am using the following code example to add Instagram photo sharing to my iphone app:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nimitparekh/files/Open%20instagram/OpenInstagramController.zip/download

I am having the same problem with the code example and also with my app.  The "Open In" menu appears with Instagram, iPhoto, etc, but none of the apps open when pushed.  Could one of you geniuses take a peek at the code example and tell me what I missing?  Thanks!

Here is the .h code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIDocumentInteractionController *docFile;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *dic;
-(IBAction)saveToInstagram:(id)sender;
```

And here in the .m code:

```
@synthesize docFile = _docFile;

-(IBAction)saveToInstagram:(id)sender {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/test.ig"];

    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];

    self.docFile.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
    self.docFile = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
    self.docFile=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
    [self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];
    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
           [self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];
    }
    else {   
        NSLog(@"No Instagram Found");
    }

}

- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {

    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;

    return interactionController;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I add the code from the project to the original post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how you construct your file NSURL instance, but one thing that's clear from your code is that you don't actually save the image you rendered.
Before calling `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` you need to do something like

```
    UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

and then something like

```
    NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75);
    [imageData writeToURL: igImageHookFile atomically:YES];
```